# Use Kerberos Golden Ticket with Metasploit

Tags: metasploit, active-directory, kerberos

Having compromised a domain controller during testing, I now wish to create persistent domain admin access. Also, operational security is important for me as I don't want to be logging into netowkr hosts using domain admin credentials.

Having generated a Kerberos golden ticket, I am able to get a SYSTEM `cmd` shell on domain joined hosts on the network with Impacket's `psexec.py`, without having to use administrator credentials.

However I would like to use the tools available within meterpreter with this access.
Is there any way I can use this generated Kerberos ticket with metasploit?